# Facebook can't read my page

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I run a site called http://www.theinspiration.com.
a few days ago my facebook share button stopped working. I can still share, but I dont get any fb meta data with, when sharing it.

When i try to linter it:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.theinspiration.com%2F2011%2F11%2Ftime-lapse-view-from-space-by-nasa%2F

I get: Critical Errors That Must Be Fixed
Error Scraping Page: Bad Response Code

If i just copy the source code, and make a plain HTML file, post it on a server and linter it, it works with all meta data. (really I just need to have the fB thumbnail image working, when sharing)

I run W3 Total Cache and CDN (amazon) and I read that this might be why, but when i disable W3 Total Cache, I still get the error.

I spend 10 hours trying to figure it out today. Can someone help me?

Thanks.
Daniel

Comment: not really sure this belongs here. seems more like a fb support question rather then a SO question, but I'll let someone else decide your fate

Answer (score 0):

I have has problems with this myself. The errors you receive are utterly useless, as I am sure the problem is it really a bad response code.

I am truly sorry that I do not remember my fix for this earlier, but I will try to remember.

Just make sure you have added an app_id and an administrator id to your metadata.
Facebook can suddenly change their required parameters, so they might have done just that.

Good luck!